# Getting rid of commas after every concatenation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do an assignment for a JavaScript class I am in, and the assignment requires that I run a forEach loop that concats every word in a given array into one string, however, for some reason, a comma is printed after every word and the space only appears after the last word when I want it after every word. Does anyone know how to fix this? [Here is the code's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnLUa.png)

'''

```js
// This is a list of words
var words = ['Loops' , 'are' , 'a' , 'great' , 'way' , 'to' , 'find' , 'elements' , 'in' , 'an' , 'array'];

// TODO: implement this function to return a string containing all words in a paragraph.
function createParagraph(word) {
  var paragraph = '';
  paragraph = paragraph + word  + ' ';
  return paragraph;
}

words.forEach((word) => createParagraph(word));
// Prints paragraph to console
console.log(createParagraph(words));

// don't change this line
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = createParagraph;
}
```

'''

Comment: Just do `words.join(' ')`. If you can't do that, then you need to declare `paragraph` outside the loop so that it's persistent, and then log `paragraph` at the end. (also, consider changing the function name, a call of `createParagraph` doesn't create a paragraph)

Comment: Where should I add words.join?

Comment: That's all you need. `console.log(words.join(' '))` done